# Fix CPU overheating after Sleep | Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, linux-kernel

I have:

```
Linux mx18 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-2~mx17+1 (2019-05-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output of the lscpu command:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               848.095
CPU max MHz:           3200.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4984.22
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3

*-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 4243WJZ
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Available
       serial: 1ZJNX16D2HP
       slot: Not Available
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
          serial: Not Supported by CPU
          slot: CPU
          size: 931MHz
          capacity: 3200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz

Kernel: 4.19.0-5-amd64 x86_64
```

PC: `LENOVO product: 4243WJZ v: ThinkPad T520`

The output of the sensors command:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +91.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +91.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +81.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The CPU goes back normale after stoping these processors `xfsettingsd` `volumeicon` `clipit` or after `reboot`

And I Know this problem doesn't relate to something I install or uninstall this problem was from the new formate Comment ask anything :)

Comment: Where is the temperature shown in your question?

Comment: Does the case feel hot? (Does it heat up during sleep or after wakeup?). To generate this much heat your CPU is actually under a non-trivial load and your sleep time on battery would be limited to only a few hours.

Comment: It happens after wakeup only, and it's hot (195 Fahrenheit) @user3528438